# How to convert scanner to String or List

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner with many lines of text(representing number) and I want to convert all the text in the scanner to a List.
Example:

```java
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
```

input.txt:

```
000110100110
010101110111
111100101011
101101001101
011011111110
011100011001
110010011100
000001011100
101110100110
010001011100
011111001010
100111100101
111111000010
```

My first thought was to convert it to a String by changing the delimiter to something I know is not in the file:

```java
myScanner.useDelimiter("impossible String");
String content = myScanner.next();
```

and then use

```java
List<String> fullInput = Arrays.asList(content.split("\n"));
```

However, it gives me problems later on with parsing the numbers on the scanner. I've tried debugging it but I can't seem to understand the problem. For example, I made it print the String to the console before parsing it. It would print a proper number(asString) and then give me NumberFormatException when it is supposed to parse.

Here's the runnable code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        myScanner.useDelimiter("impossible String");
        String content = myScanner.next();
        List<String> fullInput = Arrays.asList(content.split("\n"));
        System.out.println(fullInput.get(1));
        System.out.println(Long.parseLong(fullInput.get(1)));
    }
```

This is what I ended up using after the first didn't work:

```java
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
List<String> fullInput = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNextLine())
    fullInput.add(myScanner.nextLine());
```

Do you know what's wrong with the first method or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Since you don't show the Strings, nor how they have to be split, this question may remain difficult to answer. Please, always see your question and problem from our point of view when asking, folks who know nothing but what you show and tell us.

Comment: The final result is that fullInput would be a list of all the lines read by the scanner?  In that case, change sc.hasNext() to sc.hasNextLine() and sc.next() to sc.nextLine().

Comment: If your goal is to simply read the all lines of the file as `String[]` use `Files.readAllLines`.  You can then wrap that as a `List` using `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: I get the feeling that the *real* problem is occurring when you try to parse the lines as numbers.  That could be due to something like leading / trailing whitespace on the number strings.  Try using `Integer.parseInt(someString.trim())`

Comment: @StephenC You were right. I added the .trim() function and it works perfectly now.
However, a File.readAllLines() method doesn't seem to exist

Comment: It is `Files.readAllLines`.  That is `java.nio.file.Files` ... not `java.io.File`.  The method has existed since Java 8.

Comment: @StephenC Can you turn your comments to one answer so I can accept it? Your trim solution fixed the problem and your Files.readAllLines suggestion will be useful for me and other in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to do here, `Scanner` is the wrong solution.

If your goal is to simply read the all lines of the file as `String[]` you can use the `Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)` method ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset))) to do this. You could then wrap that as a `List` using `Arrays.asList(...)`.

What you are actually doing *could* work under some circumstances.  But one possible problem is that `String.split("\n")` only works on systems where the line terminator is a single `NL` character.  On Windows, the line terminator is a `CR` `NL` sequence.  And in that case, `String.split("\n")` will leave a `CR` at the end of all but the last string / line.  That would be sufficient to cause `Long.parseLong(...)` to throw a `NumberFormatException`.  (The `parseXxx` methods do not tolerate extraneous characters such as whitespace in the argument.)

A possible solution to the extraneous whitespace problem is to trim the string; e.g.

```
  System.out.println(Long.parseLong(fullInput.get(1).trim()));
```

The `trim()` method ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim())) returns a string with any leading and/or trailing whitespace removed.

But there is another way to deal with this.  If you don't care whether each number in the input file is on a separate line, you could do something like this:

```
  Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
  List<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
  while (myScanner.hasNextLong()) {
      numbers.append(myScanner.nextLong());
  }
```

Finally, @ChengThao makes a valid point.  It *looks* like these are binary numbers.  If they are in fact binary, then it makes more sense to parse them using `Long.parseLong(string, radix)` with a `radix` value of 2.  However if you parse them as decimal using `parseLong` (as you are currently doing) the  values in your question *will* fit into a `long` type.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are parsing a string that represents a number that's beyond the size of an integer.

`int` values can be between -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

`fullInput.get(1)` gives you `010101110111` which is greater than `2,147,483,647`.

You can use long.

```
long val = Long.parseLong(fullInput.get(1));
```

If the string represents binary numbers and you want to convert them to int, then you need to provide the base when parsing the string.

```
int val = Integer.parseInt(fullInput.get(1), 2);
```